# How can I compute the diameter of the circle that circumscribes an irregular object?

Tags: matlab, function

[image: green line]

I want a function to compute and get the diameter of the circle that circumscribes the object. Is there a built-in function in MATLAB to do this? Otherwise, what can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Try this algorithm:

1. Compute the average x and average y for every point in the irregular object.  This is done by taking the x and y component for every point and add them into the total x and total y and then divide by the number of points.  This average x and average y point algorithm gives you a non-weighted center of the object.
2. Use that center point to compute the distance for every point in the irregular object again.  Keeping the largest distance as the radius of the object.
3. Use the center point and the radius to compute the circumference.

I am submitting proof that the distance between the 2 points that are furthest apart in the object fails with a simple triangle.  See image below.  Also, the big-O notation for computing the two points that are the furthest apart is x^2.  The big-O for this algorithm is 2x. The diameter of the circle in the image would be computed as 20; distance between -10,0 and 10,0.  A circle of diameter 20 will not encompass the point @ 0,-11.  Any movement of the circle would automatically remove at least one of the two points used to compute the diameter of the circle because both points are on tangents.

[image]

Comment: This is not correct, in most cases the resulting circle will touch the object in one point. The circumscribed circle should touch at least two points.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it fails? Because I'm quite sure that his algorithm will provide the correct result. The only restriction is that the data points for the irregular object have to be evenly distributed in order for the average to be non-weighted, which is needed to fulfill your demand.

Comment: I had to edit my answer to provide the image proof that the distance between the two farthest points fails.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose M is a mask in BW, just do :

```
 [b_x,b_y] = find(bwperim(M)== 1)
```

Check this function [bwperim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html)

Comment: Warning: `bwperim` requires the image processing toolbox.  Also, this only finds the locations along the perimeter.  This doesn't find the diameter of the circle that contains the object.

Comment: I coudln't answer all the question, so this is just a help ... :)